# Are those two numbers transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, lambert-w

Suppose, $u$ solves the equation $$u^u=\pi$$ and $v$ solves the equation $$v\cdot e^v=\pi$$

So, we have $u=e^{W(\ln(\pi))}$ and $v=W(\pi)$. $u$ and $v$ should be the real solutions (in this case, they are unique). If someone can prove that $u$ and $v$ are transcendental, the next step would be to show that every solution is transcendental, but for the moment, the real case is sufficient.

- Are $u$ and $v$ transcendental ?

The Lindemann-Weierstrass-theorem does not help here because $\pi$ is transcendental and $\ln(\pi)$ and $W(\ln(\pi))$ are probably (does anyone know a proof ?) transcendental.

The algdep-command of PARI/GP does neither indicate the algebraicy of $u$ nor the algebraicy of $v$. So, if $u$ or $v$ is algebraic, the minimal polynomial must have high degree or coefficients with a large absolute value.

Comment: This looks like one of these problems that are open and still very, very far from being solved.

Comment: Do you agree with the new modality of not publishing separately the answers? I do not. With the sizeable number of questions, each answer given, not many people will read.

Comment: @Piquito I do not quite understand what the new modality is. Please explain it with other words.

Comment: Simple dear friend. Before, when an answer to a question was received, it appeared as new reception of posters with the name of who solved the problem. But not now and I wonder who read the answer if  at the time that has been sent many others have proposed new questions. In any case now read the answers much less people than before because these answers are put in the post where the problem has been formulated (I mean in the question $20^{th}$ or $30^{th}$ or more, in particular the difficult answer. Who read now an answer to a  for longtime unanswered question? Apologize for bad English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$u^u=ve^v=\pi\Rightarrow u^u=e^{v+\ln v}=\pi\Rightarrow\begin{cases}u\approx1.85411\\v\approx 1.07364\end{cases}$$
The function $f(x)=x^x$ is injective for $x\gt 1$ and so is $g(x)=xe^x$ for $x\gt 0$ hence the finded $u$ and $v$ are unique real solutions.

Besides $u$ cannot be rational because if
$$x=\left(\frac ab\right)^{\frac ab}\iff b^ax^b-a^a=0$$ then $x$ is algebraic but we know that $\pi$ is trascendental. It follows that $u$ is algebraic irrational or trascendental.

On the other hand, Geldfond-Schneider theorem ensures that if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic with $a\notin\{0,1\}$ and $b$ irrational then $a^b$ is trascendental so it is not impossible that $u$ would be algebraic but it could be trascendental also. At the current state of knowledge on this topic, we can not guarantee something more on the nature of $u$ besides of it is not rational. We only know that $u$ is algebraic of degree greater than $1$ or trascendental, nothing more.

Instead, $v$ could be rational provided $e^v$ is trascendental and we  ran into the same impasse. I stop here.

Comment: How could I overlook that $u$ cannot be rational ? (+1) for showing this.

Comment: It is showed after "Besides $u$ cannot be........."

Comment: I noticed it, therefore I upvoted the answer. You obviously misunderstood my comment :)

Comment: I did not know "overlook", excuse me.

Comment: I did not overlook your proof, I overlooked the possibility to prove that $u$ is irrational. Maybe an unlucky way to formulate it. The meaning of "overlook" is in fact "not realizing", I shouldn't have used this formulation because it is quite misleading.

Comment: Now I understand. They are things that happen. I know a very good mathematician who openly admits he can not solve many questions from the Olympics for teenagers.