# When do these common solutions involving the Lambert W function come out as integers, rational numbers, or algebraic numbers?

Tags: number-theory, lambert-w

The solutions to $2^x=2x$ are trivially given as $x=1,2$, but the algebraic solution involving the Lambert W function is given by

$$x=\frac{W_k(-\frac12\ln(2))}{-\ln(2)}=\frac12e^{-W_k\left(-\frac12\ln(2)\right)}$$

I was wondering if it were possible to deduce whether or not $x$ where an integer, rational, and/or algebraic number.

From the original problem, I can deduce the solution cannot be a rational number unless it were a positive whole number.  From there, it is easy to show that $2,4$ are the only real solutions.

This question is related to "[Are those two numbers transcendental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943458/are-those-two-numbers-transcendental)"

Comment: First of all: the real solutions are $x=1,2$ and **not** $x=2,4$. And with the function $$f(k) = \frac{W_k(-\frac12\ln(2))}{-\ln(2)}$$
you have $f(0)=1$ and $f(-1)=2.$ All other solutions from different branches are complex.

Comment: $x = 1, 2$ are the only real solutions to the equation $2^x = 2x$ since the function $x \mapsto 2^x - 2x$ is strictly convex. If $z$ is a complex solution of $2^z = 2z$, then $z$ cannot be algebraic due to [*Gelfond-Schneider theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).